# Changing the system language globally

Tags: macos, language

I just installed Mac OS X Lion on an iMac.

I noticed that the system language during installation and log in screen is Spanish (my primary language). But, once inside (desktop, etc) is English.

I want **everything** to be in English. Including the log in screen etc. How do I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this link [How to change the language of the login window](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4102?viewlocale=en_US), I hope it will help you.